# Select multiple variables with Regex inside a single string

Tags: regex

**Regex101 link**

https://regex101.com/r/wOwFEV/2

---

**Background**

I have a dump of nmap reports and I want to extract data from to digest.

---

I have various inputs similar to:

```
23/tcp   open  telnet     SMC SMC2870W Wireless Ethernet Bridge
```

The latter three variables change, but the common denominator is:

- The first value is ALWAYS `23/tcp`
- They are ALWAYS separated by **more than one** space
- There will ALWAYS be four values

I would like to use Regex to pluck each "variable" and assign it to a group.

Right now, I have

```
(?sm)(?=^23\/tcp)(?<port>.*?)\s*open
```

Which grabs `23/tcp` and assigns it to `<port>`

But I also want to grab:

- `open` and assign it to `<state>`
- `telnet` and assign it to `<service>`
- `SMC SMC2870W Wireless Ethernet Bridge` and assign it to `<description>`

If not an answer, I think knowing how to grab values between '2 or more' white spaces will solve this, but I can't find any similar examples!

Comment: Just add more capture groups that match each part of the line.

Comment: I figured it out, see answer. My issue was that the "values" changes so I was having issues figuring out how to select them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more specific regexp is:

```
(?sm)(?=^23\/tcp)(?<port>\d+\/\w+)\s+(?<state>\w*?)\s+(?<service>\w*?)\s+(?<description>.*?)\s$
```

This restricts the port to be digits/alphanumeric, and state and service to be alphanumeric. It only uses `.*` for the description, since it's arbitrary text.

And with this change, it's not necessary to require that there be at least 2 spaces between each field, it will work with any number of spaces.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wOwFEV/5)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it.

```
(?sm)(?=^23\/tcp)(?<port>.*?)\s{2,}(?<state>.*?)\s{2,}(?<service>.*?)\s{2,}(?<description>.*?)$
```

Will do exactly what I described.

https://regex101.com/r/wOwFEV/3

Comment: You should use `\w+` instead of `.*?` to match alphanumeric strings.

Comment: Why? Updating that in my linked example causes it to not work.

Comment: Not the last group, since it can have spaces in the description. and port should be `\d+/\w+`. In general, you should try to be specific when the format is more restricted.

Comment: I agree, I should try to be as specific as possible. Adding your suggestion breaks my example, can you go to the link, update the example, and commented an updated link for me to see? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: My actual input is a few hundred thousand lines. I'm forcing the capture of `23/tcp` so I can -match it in my script. Basically, I'm using it as a signal to the script to "Hey look at this line"

Comment: You could just use `(?<port>23/tcp)` to force it to match only those lines.